# Create USER in SQL Server generates error: SUBQUERY RETURNED MORE THAN 1 VALUE

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

I have a Delphi XE3 app which create users and logins in a SQL Server database. I have used FireDAC `TAdConnection`, `TADQuery` and two `TAdScript` for executing SQL statements to create the users and logins. When I try to create login on SQL Server, the SQL statement for creating logins works fine

```
CREATE LOGIN LOGIN_NAME 
WITH PASSWORD='PASSWORD', CHECK_POLICY = OFF, 
DEFAULT_DATABASE = DATABASE
```

But when I try to create the user over database

```
CREATE USER USER_NAME 
FOR LOGIN LOGIN_NAME WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo
```

the code returns an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=,<,<=,>,>= or when the subquery is used as an expression

I've tried to execute the SQL statement using `TAdConnection`, `TAdQuery` and `TADScript`, but all of them returns the same error.

Could you help please?

**UPDATE 1:** thanks for your help and comments

This is the result when I use SQL Server Management Studio for creating the Database USER

```
CREATE USER KDESAR12 FOR LOGIN KDESAR12 
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo
```

Result

> (1 row(s) affected)

The query used to get the Database's Trigger

```
select * from KACTUSDESARROLLO.sys.triggers where parent_class_desc = 'DATABASE'
```

Returns 0 rows

My Delphi Code is as follows:

```
//Using TADScript
  try
    lStSQL := 'SET CMDSEP ;';
    lStSQL := lStSQL + ' USE MY_DATABASE_NAME; ';

    lStSQL := lStSQL + ' CREATE USER KDESAR12 FOR LOGIN KDESAR12 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo;';

    ADScript1.SQLScripts.Add.SQL.Text := lStSQL;
    ADScript1.ValidateAll;
    ADScript1.ExecuteAll;

  except on E: exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  end;

//Using TADQuery
  try
    lStSQL := ' CREATE USER KDESAR12 FOR LOGIN KDESAR12 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo;';

    ADQuery2.SQL.Add (lStSQL);
    ADQuery2.ExecSQL;

  except on E: exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  end;

//Using TADConnection
  try
    lStSQL := ' CREATE USER KDESAR12 FOR LOGIN KDESAR12 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo;';

    ADConnection1.ExecSQL (lStSQL);

  except on E: exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  end;
```

All components returns the same error

Comment: Have you tried that instruction on the SQL Server Management Studio ?. You will be able to narrow possibilities, determining if the problem lies within the ADO components, or your database themselve.

Comment: "select * from sys.triggers where parent_class_desc = 'MY_DATABASE_NAME'" is incorrect.  Should be "select * from MY_DATABASE_NAME.sys.triggers where parent_class_desc = 'DATABASE' "

Comment: thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft It returns 0 rows too

`select * from KACTUSDESARROLLO.sys.triggers where parent_class_desc = 'DATABASE'`

Answer (score 4):

The only way that statement can cause that error is a DDL trigger.  EG

```
CREATE TRIGGER create_user_trigger 
ON DATABASE 
FOR create_user
AS 
   declare @id int = (select object_id from sys.objects);
;
go
```

Comment: Erik, does the same happen if you run these commands from the management studio? If not, could you provide your Delphi code?

Comment: Execute the code, please: select *
from sys.triggers
where parent_class_desc = 'DATABASE'

Comment: @Victoria Delphi Code using TADQuery

`try
    lStSQL := ' CREATE USER KDESAR12 FOR LOGIN KDESAR12 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo;';

    ADQuery2.SQL.Add (lStSQL);
    ADQuery2.ExecSQL;

  except on E: exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  end;`

Comment: @Victoria Delphi Code Using TAdConnection

`try
    lStSQL := ' CREATE USER KDESAR12 FOR LOGIN KDESAR12 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo;';

    ADConnection1.ExecSQL (lStSQL);

  except on E: exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  end;`

Comment: @Victoria in Management Studio runs fine. I attach the Delphi Code

using a TADScript

`try
    lStSQL := 'SET CMDSEP ;';
    lStSQL := lStSQL + ' CREATE USER KDESAR12 FOR LOGIN KDESAR12 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo;';

    ADScript1.SQLScripts.Add.SQL.Text := lStSQL;
    ADScript1.ValidateAll;
    ADScript1.ExecuteAll;

  except on E: exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  end;`

Comment: You can use SQL Profiler or Extended Events to any other commands Delphi is sending.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I ended testing the code against another database in another server, and it created the login just fine. 
So, I asked the DBA for differences between those environments, and he pointed me to a server trigger that he was using for auditing purposes. Once he disabled it on the first server, the code worked as expected.

For posterity, besides checking for database triggers as @David Browne - Microsoft stated, one can check for server triggers like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.server_triggers
```

thanks again